# com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets, jersey

Hi i am developing a spring + jersey project with maven 3.3.3. . i am using dependency jersey+spring in maven. but when i try to start the server an error occuring. the error shows :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

my pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.marvel.rest</groupId>
<artifactId>aFSchedulerMaven</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>JerseyEJBArchetype Jersey Webapp</name>

<build>
    <finalName>aFSchedulerMaven</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>quartz</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet</groupId>
        <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6.SEC01</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

and my web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

```
<display-name>Iris Health Scheduler</display-name>
<description>Appointments Scheduler Software for MARVEL-Health</description>

<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>aFSchedulerMaven.root</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener> 

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/marvel-servlet.xml /WEB-INF/classes/dataAccessContext-local.xml /WEB-INF/classes/dataAccessContext-Extra.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyRESTServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.marvel.scheduler.services.rest.impl</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.marvel.scheduler.services.rest.responsefilter.ResponseCorsFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyRESTServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <!-- Redirects to "welcome.htm" for dispatcher handling -->
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errorpage.html</location>
</error-page>
```

please help me to over come this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: You're including both dependencies `jersey-server` and `jersey-spring` as well. Try removing `jersey-server` dependency from the project. Also not you have included `jersey-server` twice in pom.

Comment: hi, i removed the jersey-server from my pom.xml. but now the error shows : -----------      **SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener      
     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)**

Comment: What is the server you're deploying your app in?

Comment: i am running in eclipse kepler with tomcat 7

Comment: Does your app have servlet-api.jar in WEB-INF/lib if it does, it should be of version 3.0 since Tomcat7 supports that

Comment: now i am using **<dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.1</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>**                   but still error showing : **Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)**